# Scanning from HP PhotoSmart C4580 - what is SANE?

Tags: scanning, sane

I have a multifunction HP printer/scanner. I've always used it wirelessly with a PC before now, but want to connect it to my Maverick laptop. I have hplip installed and have connected the machine to the computer via USB (wireless is not supported.) The printer works just fine, but when I try to scan, the scanner's console (not the computer, but the window on the scanner itself) tells me there's an error.

I've looked at the hplip [documentation for my machine](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/photosmart/photosmart_c4500_series.html#note3), and it says, "Scan supported means that PC initiated scan using a SANE compatible software application is supported over parallel, USB, or network (depending on I/O connection)."

What is SANE? I'm assuming it's a driver that's already installed, but where do I find a SANE compatible software application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still can't claim to understand exactly what SANE is, other than some kind of driver. But you can find a list of compatible GUI apps at [The SANE Project website](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-frontends.html).

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert!

Try to install the XSANE or SANE package in Synaptic. You might also need to install `libsane-hpao` which contains SANE's backend drivers for HP scanners. Start either XSANE or SANE in the menu-graphics.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

SANE is a program talking to your scanner hardware.

I have the same printer. I installed it using HPLIP which is installed by default in Ubuntu and scanning worked out of the box (install `hplip-gui` if you want the graphical menu).

However the printing driver added extra space (extra margins) so I uninstalled to try with another driver, installing it as a network printer through CUPS and using the hpijs driver instead of hp-cups. Which fixed my printing but broke scanning...

Installing the multifunction again through HPLIP toolbox added it as local printer and fixed scanning. So I keep the network version as default printer and renamed the local version to "scanner" to avoid confusion.